# Laravel - way to sum total_balance of all children.balance columns with just one request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to simplify my data structuring. I want to get sum of balances in children accounts of a parent account. Here is how my object is structured:

- Account Types

  - Children Types

    - Account 1 ( has balance of 9000 )
    - Account 2 ( has balance of 5000 )

I want to get total balance of all children accounts:

- Account Types

  - Children Types - total_balance = 14000

**How to do this without looping through the object, but using only the query builder of Laravel?**

This is the request in my controller:

```
    $user = \Auth::user()->id;
    $accounts = AccountType::where('parent_id', 0)
    ->where('virtual', '=', 0)
    ->with(['children', 'children.accounts' => function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', $user);
    }])
    ->get();

    return $accounts;
```

And this is the object that I get:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Savings",
"parent_id": 0,
"virtual": 0,
"created_at": "2016-10-27 10:28:59",
"updated_at": "2016-10-27 10:28:59",
"children": [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "General Savings",
    "parent_id": 1,
    "virtual": 0,
    "created_at": "2016-10-27 10:28:59",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-27 10:28:59",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "institution_id": 0,
        "balance": 9000,
        "account_nickname": "Money Laundering",
        "is_primary": 1,
        "account_type_id": 2,
        "user_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2016-10-31 16:47:23",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-31 16:47:23"
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "institution_id": 0,
        "balance": 5000,
        "account_nickname": "Moneymarket Savings",
        "is_primary": 0,
        "account_type_id": 2,
        "user_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2016-10-31 16:48:30",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-31 16:48:30"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Could you `$balance =  array_sum(array_pluck($accounts->toArray(), 'children.accounts.balance'));` ?

Comment: Yes, this works, but I have to loop the accounts object as so


  foreach($accounts as $account){
   foreach($account->toArray()['children'] as $child_account){
    $balance = array_sum(array_pluck($child_account['accounts'], 'balance'));
    dd($balance);    
   }
  }

Comment: You could define in your `accounts` model `totalBalance` as `sum(balance)`. Then you could say `$accounts->children->accounts->totalBalance`. You could use `children.accounts.totalBalance` in your query

Comment: This didn't work in account model unfortunately


return $this->sum('balance');

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a list of all account types a user has containing a the `total_balance` of all accounts under each account_type:

```php
$userAccountTypes = DB::table('account_types AS at')
    ->select(DB::Raw('*, SUM(a.balance) AS total_balance'))
    ->join('account_types AS ct', 'ct.parent_id', '=', 'at.id')
    ->join('accounts AS a', 'a.account_type_id', '=', 'ct.id')
    ->where('at.parent_id', 0)
    ->where('a.user_id', $user)
    ->groupBy('ct.id')
    ->get();
```